# Storing the Google OAuth Authorization Token in Database

Tags: php, mysql, google-oauth

I am building a portal where multiple users can log in to their multiple Gmail accounts.  I have successfully retrieved the token value, However, I want to store that in my database but I am unable to store it.

Below is the code I am using:

```
function mInititalize(){
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://mail.google.com/');
    $client->setClientId(Config('gmail.client_id'));
$client->setClientSecret(Config('gmail.client_secret'));
$client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost:81'.Config('gmail.redirect_url'));
    $loginURL = $client->createAuthUrl();
return redirect($loginURL);
}
```

**After Redirection or user login**

```
function mGetToken(){
 $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode( 'code'); // here i get the 'code' from login URL 
 I pass this code to get token I successfully get token 
     $oAuth = new Google_Service_Oauth2( $client);
     $userData = $oAuth->userinfo_v2_me->get(); // get current user detail
    }
```

I want to store `$token` value in database, but I am getting error message

```
>Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed
```

Please anyone help me to solve this issue.  Thanks.

Comment: You didn't show us how you're trying to insert it into DB.

Comment: **I am using Insert Query** INSERT INTO access_token_table (access_token)
VALUES ($token->access_token)

Comment: Why do you want to store the `Access Token`. That token expires in 3,600 seconds. You should store the `Refresh Token`.

Comment: Look into the API `client->getAccessToken()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest storing OAuth credential information for the Google API, not in your database, but through the API itself.  If you're intending to use it any authentication manner, you'll run into problems, as the docs state:

> > Access tokens periodically expire and become invalid credentials for a related API request.  [Google Identity Platform: Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer)

But, the same docs also show a way that you can set or retrieve the token natively within the API.  Since it's data relating to google's auth'ing process, and since it might go stale if you store it, it seems best to just let them handle it and work with the API.  The same source:

> > If you need to apply an access token to a new Google_Client object—for example, if you stored the access token in a user session—use the setAccessToken method:

```
$client->setAccessToken($access_token);
$client->getAccessToken();
```